# What does “Six boulots” mean?

Tags: expressions, oral, registre-familier

While in a conversation with my mates, I came across some expression with “six boulots”. I was pretty sure that they were not talking about six jobs and just like my previous queries I am well above 90% that I heard it right. I couldn't interpret the whole sentence but it was like having “six boulots” or something similar!

This is one of the many instances I come across, words like these either I completely forget it or sometimes google has an answer and the rest are in the FSE database :-) .

Comment: On the [TLFi website](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv4/showps.exe?p=combi.htm;java=no;), you can look up words by pronunciation. This is the same dictionary (the *[Trésor de la langue française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)) as www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ , with opaque URLs but with this extra search capability.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've heard *[ciboulot](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciboulot)*, which originally is the name of a small onion. It's sometimes used figuratively for “head” or “brain” in popular language.

Comment: I concur. "Six boulots" doesn't mean anything particular, "ciboulot" is the most plausible hypothesis.

Comment: Yes , I am now sure that it was *ciboulot* taking the context into consideration .The subject in reality was a dude who finished his coding part within a few days from the project conception while others were yet to get a grip on the details ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec, ciboulot est utilisé en tant que juron comme dans la phrase: "Il a été rapide en ciboulot" signifiant: il a été *vraiment* très rapide.

Answer (score -2):

Six boulots could be six escargots. There is a type of snails that it called boulot. In the U.S sometimes we see it sold in fancy seafoods market and it comes from Canada.

Comment: You mean "bulots", right? It's not the same sound.